# padding when a floated object element is inside

Tags: css, css-float, padding

i have the below html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
        <img alt="Giannis Simeonidis" src="logo2.png" width="300" height="220"/> 
        <object width="550" height="200" id="banner">
            <param name="movie" value="banner.swf" />
            <embed src="banner.swf" width="550" height="200"  
                    wmode="transparent" 
                    type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
            </embed>
        </object>
        <div id="menu">
          <object width="600" height="20">
             <param name="movie" value="menu.swf" />
             <embed src="menu.swf" width="600" height="20"  
                    wmode="transparent" 
                    type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
              </embed>
         </object> 
        </div>
    </div><!--End of header-->
</div>
```

and the css is:

```
#wrapper{
 /*background: url(header_bg.jpg) repeat-x;*/
 background: url(container_bg2.png) repeat-y;
 margin: 0 auto;
 margin-top: 20px;
 width: 900px;
}


#header{
 width: 900px;
 padding: 0 10px;
}

#banner{
 float: right;
}

#menu{
 clear: right;
 padding-left: 13px;
}
```

For some reason the right padding applied to the #header is not working; Any ideas?

Comment: Can you give a simpler code clearly stating the problem. The current code loads of images and objects (which, of course its not able to on my local computer)

Comment: header{
width: 900px; padding: 0 10px; }

Comment: the probleb is in this part of code. The padding of 10px works only on the left side, the right side is not affected.

Answer (score 0):

The width of the wrapper is 900px.
The width of the header is 900px + 10px Left Padding + 10px Right Padding 
= 920px.

You are trying to fit a 920px div inside a 900px div. Either make the wrapper wider to 920px or the header shorter to 880px.